# How to set dependencies for a macro in Rust?

Tags: rust

I wrote a macro in a crate and import it in the main function of a main project.

The macro depends on:

```rust
use chrono::{Utc, Local, DateTime, Date};
```

Currently I include the dependency in the Cargo.toml of the main project.

Will I need to do the same for all main projects? Or Can I declare the dependency in the Cargo.toml of the macro crate?

```
//lib.rs //Mymacro 
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! time {
    () => {
        use chrono::{Utc, Local, DateTime, Date};
        let local_datetime: DateTime<Local> = Local::now();
        println!("{:?}",local_datetime);
    }
}
```

```
//main.rs // main project
extern crate Mymacro;

#[macro_use]
fn main() {
    time!();
}

// Cargo.toml
[dependencies] 
chrono=""
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Will I need to do the same for all main projects? Or Can I declare the dependency in the Cargo.toml of the macro crate?

You can, by either (1) having your macro call a function in your library or (2) by re-exporting `chrono` (partially or completely).

---

Let's consider that we have a workspace, with a `lib` and `bin` crate.

```
[workspace]
members = [
    "bin",
    "lib",
]
```

Now in your `Cargo.toml` for the `lib` crate you'd include `chrono` as a dependency, like you otherwise would.

```
[dependencies]
chrono = "0.4"
```

While the `Cargo.toml` for the `bin` crate only has the dependency of `lib`.

```
[dependencies]
lib = { path = "../lib" }
```

---

Now, let's consider that `main.rs` in the `bin` crate looks like this:

```rust
use lib::time;

fn main() {
    time!();
}
```

*It will remain the same, regardless of which option you go with.*

---

*The following snippets represent `lib.rs`.*

---

### Library Function

If you never actually return any `chrono` specific types, then this might be the *easiest*. As you avoid re-exporting chrono completely.

```rust
use chrono::{DateTime, Local};

pub fn _time() {
    let local_datetime: DateTime<Local> = Local::now();
    println!("{:?}", local_datetime);
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! time {
    () => {
        $crate::_time();
    };
}
```

*If you don't want `_time` to appear in the documentation of your library, then you can use the `#[doc(hidden)]` attribute.*

### Re-export some items

Alternatively, if you want everything to remain within the macro, then you can re-export the `chrono` types it uses, and prepend the types in your macro with `$crate::`.

The downside to this, is that if your `bin` crate needs a `chrono` type that is not re-exported, then that can be an "annoyance" and thus `bin` would need to depend on `chrono = "0.4"` anyways.

```rust
pub use chrono::{DateTime, Local};

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! time {
    () => {
        let local_datetime: $crate::DateTime<$crate::Local> = $crate::Local::now();
        println!("{:?}", local_datetime);
    };
}
```

*In `main.rs` if you instead do `use lib::*;`, then you'd of course not need to prepend `$crate::`, but it's best to avoid doing `use lib::*;`.*

### Re-export Chrono

Lastly, if you need the `chrono` types in you `bin` crate. Then you can also re-export the whole `chrono` crate with `pub extern crate chrono;`.

Note that this time, you need to prepend the types in your macro with `$crate::chrono::`.

```rust
pub extern crate chrono;

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! time {
    () => {
        let local_datetime: $crate::chrono::DateTime<$crate::chrono::Local> =
            $crate::chrono::Local::now();
        println!("{:?}", local_datetime);
    };
}
```

Comment: omg i love you. this was so confusing.